# Is it possible to intercept and cancel a FragmentTransaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have two tabs on an ActionBar (Sherlock). In some cases I want to ask the user for  confirmation if she tries to leave the current tab and stop the tab change if it's not confirmed. This is mostly due to stopping a process before the user goes to fiddle with its settings on the other tab.

When I was using TabHost, I had a pretty ugly but doable solution with a OnTouchListener on the tab itself, so I could intercept the event before it ever was really handled. It seems that the ActionBar tabs can't have touch listeners, so that seems out of the question.

Now with ActionBar I have TabListeners that handle the detaching and attaching on the FragmentTransaction. Is there any simple way to cancel the transaction? I guess I could do checks on onTabUnselected and onTabSelected and just not do the corresponding detach and attach operations but that feels a bit complicated.

If stopping the tab change sounds overly stupid I'm also open for other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I ended up doing in case anyone stumbles here. I couldn't find any reasonable way to stop the tab from changing or getting hold of the tab views to attach a touch listener. Irritating, to say the least.

Instead I used the TabListener to attach an empty fragment in the case when I wanted to turn the user back to the original tab. On this fragment's onResume() I opened a dialog that offers the choice of continuing to the second tab or returning to the first. On either case I just call the action bar's setSelectedNavigationItem() with the correct tab and the TabListener will handle the transfer, disposing of my empty fragment.

In the end it actually works pretty nicely.